# Size of derived class in virtual base class function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, gcc, typeof

Consider the following code

```
class A {
    int x, y;
public:
    A(){}
    virtual void PrintSize(){ cout << sizeof(typeof(*this)) << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    int a, b, c;
public:
    B(){}
};

int main() {
    A obja;
    B objb;

    obja.PrintSize();
    objb.PrintSize();
}
```

The intent of "PrintSize()" is to get the size of the current class where we are calling it from. What happens is that this-keyword refers to class A even though we are calling it from B. We don't want this since we need this function to be general for child classes.

We could obviously redefine the function verbatim to every class. The code would become harder to hande since there's so many unnesessary lines. Not to mention that re-writing the function to every class would defeat the purpose of deriving it in the first place.

Here's my temporary fix:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void PrintSize(){ cout << sizeof(typeof(*this)) << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void PrintSize(){ cout << sizeof(typeof(*this)) << endl; }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    virtual void PrintSize(){ cout << sizeof(typeof(*this)) << endl; }
};

class D : public A {
public:
    virtual void PrintSize(){ cout << sizeof(typeof(*this)) << endl; }
};
```

Comment: what is `typeof`?

Comment: I don't think `typeof` is a thing in C++. I believe it's a GCC [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of this. I've always programmed with gcc so I thought it was a c++ thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CRTP idiom to do this.
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c
The idea is the parent class is a template, so you can have access to the type of the child class directly in it. 
With that, you'll be able to remove all "PrintSize" from child class.

Example :

```
template <typename Derived>
class A {
    int x, y;
public:
    A() {}
    void PrintSize() { cout << sizeof(Derived) << endl; }
};

class B : public A<B> {
    int a, b, c;
public:
    B() {}
};

class C : public A<C> {
public:
    C() {}
};

int main() {
    C objc;
    B objb;

    objc.PrintSize();
    objb.PrintSize();
}
```

The output is :

8

20

Comment: It should be noted that with CRTP you loose having a common base class. `B` and `C` inherit from different classes.

Comment: Beware that in the code provided in your answer, there is no common base type. You need a non-templated base type from which `A` inherits which provides a `virtual` interface for `void PrintSize();` Then, `A` becomes an implementation detail that should be used directly by users of your types except to inherit from it.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed! Good that this also removed the GCC dependency.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer may have solved the immediate problem, you suddenly have no common base class for `B` and `C`. They inherit from two unrelated classes, namely `A<B>` and `A<C>`.

An alternative is to create a common base that defines an interface (called `Interface` below) and to add the CRTP class template between the derived classes and the interface. This lets you keep pointers and references to `Interface` and call the `virtual` member functions using those.

Here's an example of storing pointers to the common base class in a `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() = default;

    virtual void PrintSize() const = 0;
    virtual void do_stuff() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Printer : public Interface {
    void PrintSize() const override {
        std::cout << sizeof(T) << '\n';
    }
};

class B : public Printer<B> {
    int a{};
public:
    void do_stuff() const override { std::cout << "B doing stuff\n"; }
};

class C : public Printer<C> {
    int a{}, b{}, c{};
public:
    void do_stuff() const override { std::cout << "C doing stuff\n"; }    
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> objs;

    objs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    objs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<C>());

    for(auto& ptr : objs) {
        ptr->do_stuff();
        ptr->PrintSize();
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
B doing stuff
16
C doing stuff
24
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you specifically wrote "int a{}" instead of "int a". Or do they have the same effect?

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC `int a{}` initializes `a` (sets it to `0` in this case) while leaving it as `int a` does not. Reading uninitialized variables causes undefined behavior so to not create an object with uninitialized members when there's no constructor doing it, default initializing is usually good. You can try removing `{}` [in this example](https://godbolt.org/z/nh7-Fs) and see the compiler warnings.

Comment: Aren't constructors used to initialize member variables? Wouldn't a constructor implicitly initialize those variables (in my example above with the `A(){}`)

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC No, but if you implement a constructor, you would usually initialize the members explicitly: `A() : a{} { std::cout << "constructor body\n"; }` - or setting a specific value: `A() : a{10} { ... }`

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC You can see the perhaps surprising result of not initializing the members [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bSCvmq). Exactly what happens when you read an uninitialized member is undefined. In this example it prints the number 10 **before** it's even set and then it prints another number. It could just as well crash and burn.

Comment: @Trad_NotSuitedPC ... and a [final example](https://godbolt.org/z/zU6EVg) that can explain a lot of strange bugs people have.